# Can I set a general form error with callback validator?

Tags: symfony

Can I set a general form error with callback validator? I do not want to set it to a specific field, but rather to a form in general errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to create what we call a **class** constraint, which will be applied to the `data_class` itself, not to a specific field: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#classes

Comment: Not really answering the question here. Ok for the part on callback being applied on the whole class. But how do you set an error as global to the class and not a field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code to set an error to your global form and not on a field.

```
public function isValid(ExecutionContext $context) {

    if (what ever condition) {

        // Do not set the property path as shown in the documentation
        $context->addViolation('This name sounds totally fake!', array(), null);
    }
}
```

When you do not define a property path on the context, the violation is added on top level of the form. all you have to do is **remove these two lines** given in the official documentation :

```
 $propertyPath = $context->getPropertyPath() . '.firstName';
 $context->setPropertyPath($propertyPath);
```

And afterwards simple display the global errors of your form.

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```